# Block specific url with ? with htacess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, http-status-code-403

Firstly, I can't get the correct code looking at other post here, not working for me hahahaha.

I would like to block this specific url: /2017/06/wonder-womannuestra-princesa-feminista.html?m=1 (Related to an old blogger url)

Don't know why but different ips, without referrer and user agent, are spamming (not a real visit cause after a redirection to the new one on WordPress they visit all the links in the url) my site always entering by this url and I would like to block ONLY this one.

I've tried to redirect this one with Redirection plugin but I have a redirection to all "?m=(*)" and this one is the one working, not the one related to the specific url.

I just used : `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/2017/06/wonder-womannuestra-princesa-feminista.html?m=1` but it doesn't work.

Could you help, I think the problem is that I'm not witting the correct code due to the "?" character. Many thanks.

Comment: Please do add your htaccess Rules file which you tried in your question(there is no right or wrong in efforts, tried codes), kindly do edit your question and let us know then, thank you.

Comment: Also try to be more specific... what do you actually want, do you want to redirect those requests or block those requests? You contradict yourself currently. And please try to say exactly what you mean by "always entering by this url". You cannot prevent the requests, you can only change the response your system delivers. A redirection can simply be ignored by a potential attacker. Though in 99% of the cases where someone shouts "attack!" a much more harmless explanation is the result...

Comment: Ok, sorry if I didn´t explain fine. 

@arkascha I´m having spam visits from differents ips, the first hit is always to the url mentioned, after that the ip hits all the links in the same page (so is not a real visit). What I want is to block any visit to this url.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 , I just used : RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/2017/06/wonder-womannuestra-princesa-feminista.html?m=1 but it doesnt work, the next time the spammers ips visits me they are not blocked.

Comment: @RalAMORESGONZLEZ, sure please add these rules in your question as an effort, comments are not supposed to have code in it, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With your shown samples, attempts considering that you need to block url(mentioned in comments/question), if this is the case then try following. This rule will forbid this specific url from being accessed.

Please these rules at top of your .htaccess file. Make sure to clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine ON
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/2017/06/wonder-womannuestra-princesa-feminista\.html\?m=1 [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works perfect. Now I hope I can say bye to this spammer ips following this url...

Comment: @RalAMORESGONZLEZ, Your welcome, cheers and happy learning, keep posting Good Q & A on this great forum.